# how to use websocket for android in jquery

Tags: android, jquery, websocket, alert, cordova

Hi in my android app i'm using websocket in jquery

i try to connect the connect the websocket using this script

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="cordova-1.8.0.js"></script>
```

this is a code i used to connect to websocket

```
var ITOUCH_WEBSOCKET = {"remote_address":'ws://atwerervgt',"channel":'alert'};    
(function pulse(websocketDetails){
    if ("WebSocket" in window)
      {
        alert("Websocket is supported");

         // Let us open a web socket
         var ws = new WebSocket(websocketDetails.remote_address,websocketDetails.channel);

         ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
         { 

                }

                createAlert(received_msg,received_msg.actionType==='NEW');
            } else {
               // alert("Message Received : Action Type is " + received_msg.actionType);
            }


         };
         ws.onclose = function()
         { 
            // websocket is closed.
            //alert("Connection is closed...");
            // On close reconnect again
            pulse(websocketDetails);
         };
      }
      else
      {alert("Websocket is not supported");
      }
})(ITOUCH_WEBSOCKET);
    });
```

the alert i am getting is  Websocket is not supported

can any one help me what is the problem in my websocket coding

Comment: `Websocket is not supported` What is unclear about that?

Comment: any problem with this if condition  if ("WebSocket" in window)

Comment: the condition is supposed to tell you that websocket is not supported. It doesn't work in android. It's not supported. I cannot say it more clearly

Comment: this code work fine in IOS i want to run in android OS can u help what is a error

Comment: the above web socket coding is correct r not

Comment: if it works fine on a browser that supports websockets (like iOS safari 4.2+) then I guess the coding is correct.

Comment: i don't no y it not going in side if condition any idea plz help me

Comment: it checks for support _correctly_ on Android. It's just **NOT** supported

Comment: @GNi33 u 've any idea abt websocket coding for android

Comment: @Jagan You cannot use a websocket with Android.  Just because it works with iOS does not mean it will be transferable to Android.

Comment: @Atlos thanks a lot i was searching this for a long time

Comment: If you have nativr app with embedded webviews you can use host object to add web socket implementation from java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Esailija mentioned in the comments, websockets are not supported on Android. Check out the "can I use" page":

http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

So as much as you want to use web sockets on Android you are not going to be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets work with Chrome for Android v25+:
http://caniuse.com/websockets